# SQL Join or identical id's

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following SQL instruction :

```
SELECT id_acte, idBiblio , Author_name , title , number_acte 
  FROM Actes 
       RIGHT JOIN Bibliography 
          ON idBiblio = Biblio_id 
 WHERE id = 203;
```

I have the impression that it is exactly the same as :

```
SELECT id_acte, idBiblio , Author_name , title , number_acte 
  FROM Actes, Bibliography 
 WHERE idBiblio = Biblio_id 
       AND id = 203;
```

Is there any difference at all ?

Thanks !

Comment: Change the keyword `RIGHT` to `INNER` and they are semantically equivalent.

Comment: Inner join will be considered while using multiple tables with ','. 
And Inner join and Right join are different.

Comment: We don't know which table id belongs to, so we can't really say (although we can guess). Note that nobody uses RIGHT JOIN, but you're welcome to do so if you wish. Oh, and we stopped using comma joins in 1992.

Comment: Without knowing where `id` comes from, it is impossible to say.  Always use qualified column names if you have more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference. Right join works like this:

All records matching to the instruction are taking from table on the right side (Bibliography) and then compiler try to match records from left table (Actes). In the end you can get the list of records from the Bibliography which don't have records in Actes (will be null).

In second instruction you will get only records which match (from both tables).

I hope it is clear.

Comment: Whether or not they are semantically idenictical depends on whether id belongs to the LEFT table or the RIGHT table.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't notice that, I've tried just to explain the general rule.

Comment: All clear, thanks a lot. I don't have enough credits to upvote answers yet.